# Delete events on Facebook Insights

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-insights

When I try to log some events (custom app events or purchases, for example), I receive this log :

```
error = {
    code = 100;
    message = "(#100) App ID: xxxxx, Can only have up to 300 events per app, fb_mobile_deactivate_app doesn't fit";
    type = OAuthException;
};
```

I understand that my app has already 300 events.
I would like to cleanup the current events list, in order to log new events.

Does someone know how to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hey Remy have you got any solution for above

Comment: Hi. Facebook support told me that the only solution is to create a different Facebook application.